# How to append (list in list) in list Python

Tags: python, list, 2d

```
title_list = [['determined', 'by', 'saturation', 'transfer', '31P', 'NMR']
, ['Interactions', 'of', 'the', 'F1', 'ATPase', 'subunits', 'from', 'Escherichia', 'coli'
, 'detected', 'by', 'the', 'yeast', 'two', 'hybrid', 'system']]
pc_title_list = []
for i in range(len(title_list)):
  for j in range(len(title_list[i])):
    if (title_list[i][j].isalpha() == True):
      pc_title_list[i].append(title_list[i][j].lower())
```

After My last question ([IndexError: list index out of range and python(With array 2D)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65688856/indexerror-list-index-out-of-range-and-pythonwith-array-2d)) about this, I'm getting 1 more question **how I got this Answer pattern**

```
[['determined', 'by', 'saturation', 'transfer', 'nmr'], ['interactions', 'of', 'the', 'atpase', 'subunits', 'from', 'escherichia', 'coli', 'detected', 'by', 'the', 'yeast', 'two', 'hybrid', 'system']]
```

I tried about this IndexError: list index out of range but I'm can't solve it now.

Next problem I got This

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-17-dbc1dd2e1a75> in <module>()
  8     file_out.write("{")
  9     if (i != len(pc_title_list)):
  ---> 10       text = pc_title_list[i][j]
 11       file_out.write("%d 1, " %(ans_list.index(text)))
 12     else:

 IndexError: list index out of range
```

After i'm trying to export arff file
Follow from this code

```
file_out = open("HW1_1_610510803.arff", "w")
file_out.write('@relatrion PAPERS\n')
for i in ans_list:
  file_out.write("@attribute %s NUMERIC\n" % i)
file_out.write("\n@data\n")
for i in range(0,len(pc_title_list)):
  for j in range(0,len(pc_title_list)):
    file_out.write("{")
    if (i != len(pc_title_list)):
      text = pc_title_list[i][j]
      file_out.write("%d 1, " % (ans_list.index(text)))
    else:
      file_out.write("%d 1\n" % (ans_list.index(text)))
    file_out.write("}")
file_out.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

You are getting the error because of this line

```
pc_title_list[i].append(title_list[i][j].lower())
```

Try this:-

```
title_list = [['determined', 'by', 'saturation', 'transfer', '31P', 'NMR']
, ['Interactions', 'of', 'the', 'F1', 'ATPase', 'subunits', 'from', 'Escherichia', 'coli'
, 'detected', 'by', 'the', 'yeast', 'two', 'hybrid', 'system']]
pc_title_list = []
for i in range(len(title_list)):
  temp_list = []
  for j in range(len(title_list[i])):
    if (title_list[i][j].isalpha() == True):
      temp_list.append(title_list[i][j].lower())
  pc_title_list.append(temp_list)
```

OR perhaps this might be more simpler:-

```
title_list = [['determined', 'by', 'saturation', 'transfer', '31P', 'NMR']
, ['Interactions', 'of', 'the', 'F1', 'ATPase', 'subunits', 'from', 'Escherichia', 'coli'
, 'detected', 'by', 'the', 'yeast', 'two', 'hybrid', 'system']]
pc_title_list = [[word.lower() for word in sub_list if word.isalpha()] for sub_list in title_list]
```

Comment: Thank you, and now I getting a question.
I trying to export arff file but
file_out = open("HW1_1_610510803.arff", "w")
file_out.write('@relatrion PAPERS\n')
for i in ans_list:
  file_out.write("@attribute %s NUMERIC\n" % i)
file_out.write("\n@data\n")
for i in range(0,len(pc_title_list)):
  for j in range(0,len(pc_title_list)):
    file_out.write("{")
    if (i != len(pc_title_list)):
      text = pc_title_list[i][j]
      file_out.write("%d 1, " %(ans_list.index(text)))
    else:
      file_out.write("%d 1\n" %(ans_list.index(text)))
    file_out.write("}")
file_out.close()

Comment: ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-17-dbc1dd2e1a75> in <module>()
      8     file_out.write("{")
      9     if (i != len(pc_title_list)):
---> 10       text = pc_title_list[i][j]
     11       file_out.write("%d 1, " %(ans_list.index(text)))
     12     else:

IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: You are getting error due to  for j in range(0,len(pc_title_list)): replace it with for j in range(0,len(pc_title_list[i]))

Comment: Also range(n) or range(0, n) would end at n - 1 i.e. if n is 5 then range would give 0, 1, 2, 3, 4

Answer (score 0):

**One-liner:**

```
print ([[x for x in sub if x.isalpha()] for sub in title_list])
```

Output:

```
[['determined', 'by', 'saturation', 'transfer', 'NMR'], ['Interactions', 'of', 'the', 'ATPase', 'subunits', 'from', 'Escherichia', 'coli', 'detected', 'by', 'the', 'yeast', 'two', 'hybrid', 'system']]
```

Comment: Thank you, can you teach me a new problem at my edit post.

Comment: Not allowed :). You need to close the question by accepting one answer (gray tick top left of one, mine for instance) and ask a new one. Otherwise the other answers are out of context after.

Answer (score 0):

You're constantly trying to append to an index which does not exist in your result list. This causes an out of range error.

```
test = []
>>> test[0]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#32>", line 1, in <module>
    test[0]
IndexError: list index out of range
```

It would be best to generate a list per iteration, and append that list to the result as you go.

```
result = [] # Empty list to store results

for sub in title_list:
    words = []
    for word in sub:
        if word.isalpha():
            words.append(word.lower())
    result.append(words)
```

You can also achieve this using list comprehension

```
[[word.lower() for word in sub if word.isalpha()] for sub in title_list]
#[['determined', 'by', 'saturation', 'transfer', 'nmr'], ['interactions', 'of', 'the', 'atpase', 'subunits', 'from', 'escherichia', 'coli', 'detected', 'by', 'the', 'yeast', 'two', 'hybrid', 'system']]
```

Comment: Thank you, can you teach me a new problem at my edit post.